# Split view controller - set table view as the initial view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to create a database with split view controller.

My question how to set table view as the initial view controller?

The default is the detail view controller, how can I set the table view in split view controller as the initial view controller?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might mean how do you set the master as the view controller that appears first. If that is the case this might work for you. It depends on your particular situation but it's usually best to set your `AppDelegate` as the delegate for the split view controller. Then implement this delegate method and return true.

```
extension AppDelegate : UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
    func splitViewController(_ svc: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary vc2: UIViewController, onto vc1: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

There's more you can do with this method but if I understand your question this is what you need in this case.